# pass a variable from a statefull widget to state

Tags: flutter, dart

i try to pass a variable "int counter = 0;" in a state widget ,but i don't know why i can't retrieve it , the App return me as "Null", I passed all the variables into the constructor though , (class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title, this.counter}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  int counter= 0;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      widget.counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '${widget.counter}',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Attempt to do this first: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data. After that, try learning provider: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

Comment: you didnt pass it in MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page', counter = 0 or what else you want)

Comment: or define a default value like that in constructor  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title, this.counter = 0})

Comment: Thanks Anna it was the solution , the code here : ``` class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  final String title;
  int counter;
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title, this.counter=0 }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lets first analyze code

```
 home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
 // You did not pass integer to the counter field, dart pass null to counter field


class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title, this.counter
/* here null will be initialized to the counter field */
}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  int counter= 0; // now it is null
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
```

So for this reason you get null

How to correctly pass in your scenario:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title, this.counter=0}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  int counter;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      widget.counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '${widget.counter}',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Widget`s (including `StatefulWidget`s) should *always* be immutable, should not change over their lifetime. In fact, you should see a warning if you try to add a non-`final` variable to the `StatefulWidget`, since it is a subtype of `Widget`, which has the `@immutable` annotation.

It is very rare that any logic actually takes place inside a `StatefulWidget` subclass. Instead, all the state and associated logic should be in the `State` class.

You should move `counter` into the state class like this:

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  const MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      counter++;
    }); 
  }

  // the rest is the same, except using counter instead of widget.counter
}
```